# How to extract the ID and Price from log mediator data

Tags: csv, wso2, mediator, wso2-esb

"[2017-10-16 21:04:26,658] []  INFO - LogMediator To: , WSAction: urn:mediate, SOAPAction: urn:mediate, MessageID: urn:uuid:E97D05A77885A752BE1508168066619, Direction: request, Envelope:  IDNameClassificationPrice S10_16781969 Harley Davidson ChopperMotorCycles1000 S10_19491952 Alpne Renault 1300Classic Cars600 S10_20161996 Moto Guzzi 1100iMotorcycles345 S10_46982003 Harley Davidson Eagle BikeMotorcycles345 S10_47571972 Alfa Romeo GTAClassic Cars230 S10_49621962 Lancia Delta 16VClassic Cars890 S12_10991968 Ford MustangClassic Cars560 S12_11082001 Ferrari EnzoClassic Cars900"

Hi, How to extract the ID and Price (only) of the above log mediator data in WSO2 EI 611 in payloadfactory mediator?

Comment: You're going to have to clean up and format that if you want to get any help but on SO, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**.

Comment: I did tried and here's the code : <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                <format>
                    <m:checkpriceresponse xmlns:m="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
                        <m:ID>$ctx:ID</m:ID>
                        <m:Price>$ctx:Price</m:Price>
                    </m:checkpriceresponse>
                </format>
                <args>
                    <arg value="ID"/>
                    <arg value="Price"/>
                </args>
            </payloadFactory>   This gave me a runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

Your xml:

```
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
    <format>
        <m:checkpriceresponse xmlns:m="ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
            <m:ID>$ctx:ID</m:ID>
            <m:Price>$ctx:Price</m:Price>
        </m:checkpriceresponse>
    </format>
    <args>
        <arg value="ID"/>
        <arg value="Price"/>
    </args>
</payloadFactory>
```

If you have ID and Price as properties, then you need this code:

```
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
    <format>
        <m:checkpriceresponse xmlns:m="ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
            <m:ID>$1</m:ID>
            <m:Price>$2</m:Price>
        </m:checkpriceresponse>
    </format>
    <args>
        <arg expression="$ctx:ID"/>
        <arg expression="$ctx:Price"/>
    </args>
</payloadFactory>
```

Take a look a this links:

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/PayloadFactory+Mediator
http://shriwithjava.blogspot.com.co/2015/07/how-to-use-payload-factory-in-wso2-esb.html

Comment: Thanks. I tried this :  <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                <format>
                    <m:PriceData xmlns:m="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                        <m:ID>$1</m:ID>
                        <m:Price>$2</m:Price>
                    </m:PriceData>
                </format>
                <args>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:ID"/>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:Price"/>
                </args>
            </payloadFactory> ID & Price are repeating, I get empty values <m:ID/><m:Price/>

Comment: PayloadFactory didnt work for me, I used DataMapper mediator and it solved the problem. Can someone clarify where PayloadFactory mediator *SHOULD* be used?